# How to remove rows in data frame after frequency tables in R

Tags: r

I have 3 data frames from which I have to find the continent with less than 2 countries and remove those countries(rows). The data frames are structured in a manner similar a data frame called x below:

```
    row        Country   Continent   Ranking
    1        Kenya       Africa      17
    2        Gabon       Africa      23
    3        Spain       Europe      04
    4        Belgium     Europe      03
    5        China       Asia        10
    6        Nigeria     Africa      14
    7        Holland     Europe      01
    8        Italy       Europe      05
    9        Japan       Asia        06
```

First I wanted to know the frequency of each country per continent, so I did

```
    x2<-table(x$Continent)
    x2
    Africa Europe Asia
    3        4      2
```

Then I wanted to identify the continents with less than 2 countries

```
    x3 <- x2[x2 < 10]
    x3
    Asia
    2
```

My problem now is how to remove these countries. For the example above it will be the 2 countries in Asia and I want my final data set to look like presented below:

```
    row       Country   Continent   Ranking
    1        Kenya       Africa      17
    2        Gabon       Africa      23
    3        Spain       Europe      04
    4        Belgium     Europe      03
    5        Nigeria     Africa      14
    6        Holland     Europe      01
    7        Italy       Europe      05
```

The number of continents with less than 2 countries will vary among the different data frames so I need one universal method that I can apply to all.

Comment: I think your code is `x2[ x2 <=2]`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
 library(dplyr)
 x %>%
    group_by(Continent) %>% 
    filter(n()>2)
 #   row Country Continent Ranking
 #1   1   Kenya    Africa      17
 #2   2   Gabon    Africa      23
 #3   3   Spain    Europe      04
 #4   4 Belgium    Europe      03
 #5   6 Nigeria    Africa      14
 #6   7 Holland    Europe      01
 #7   8   Italy    Europe      05
```

Or using the `x2`

```
 subset(x, Continent %in% names(x2)[x2>2])
 #    row Country Continent Ranking
 #1   1   Kenya    Africa      17
 #2   2   Gabon    Africa      23
 #3   3   Spain    Europe      04
 #4   4 Belgium    Europe      03
 #6   6 Nigeria    Africa      14
 #7   7 Holland    Europe      01
 #8   8   Italy    Europe      05
```

Answer (score 3):

A very easy way with "data.table" would be:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(x)[, N := .N, by = Continent][N > 2]
#    row Country Continent Ranking N
# 1:   1   Kenya    Africa      17 3
# 2:   2   Gabon    Africa      23 3
# 3:   3   Spain    Europe       4 4
# 4:   4 Belgium    Europe       3 4
# 5:   6 Nigeria    Africa      14 3
# 6:   7 Holland    Europe       1 4
# 7:   8   Italy    Europe       5 4
```

In base R you can try:

```
x[with(x, ave(rep(TRUE, nrow(x)), Continent, FUN = function(y) length(y) > 2)), ]
#   row Country Continent Ranking
# 1   1   Kenya    Africa      17
# 2   2   Gabon    Africa      23
# 3   3   Spain    Europe       4
# 4   4 Belgium    Europe       3
# 6   6 Nigeria    Africa      14
# 7   7 Holland    Europe       1
# 8   8   Italy    Europe       5
```

Comment: `setDT(x)[, .SD[.N>2] , Continent]` might be shorter and also slower

Comment: Thanks,but i have one more question. What if the Continents contained some NA values, how would you remove the Countries with the missing values of Continents? @akrun

Comment: @patience, so you mean "remove those with fewer than two or with `NA` values in 'Continents'"?

Comment: @patience It is not clear what you want.  If you need to remove the rows with `NA` for Continents. `x$Continent[3] <- NA; subset(x, !is.na(Continent))`